# Xamarin.Essentials.Map vs Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Map

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms 4.1 and have the following packages installed...

[image]

I see there is a Map class in both namespaces Xamarin.Essentials and Xamarin.Forms.Maps.  Why is this?  I was thinking the Essentials package was needed to make a map, but it seems it's embedded into XF itself somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Xamarin Essentials Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/maps?tabs=android)

> The Map class enables an application to open the installed map
>   application to a specific location or placemark.

ie, it's a helper to allow you to open the device's default Map application

Xamarin.Forms.Map is an actual Map widget that can be embedded within your app.

Comment: Yep. They just have merged James Montemagno's plugin in Xamarin.Essentials : https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/LaunchMapsPlugin